# Bootstrap Same Height on Table Alert Divs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

had some trouble researching this, maybe I'm just not thinking clearly. I am using Bootstrap 3 and have a table to pull in data and I am highlighting certain data with their Alert styled divs.

The problem I have is that depending on the data they all have differing heights and I want them to all be the same. I've seen other examples but they weren't utilizing a table structure.

Is there a way to do this or is my only option to ditch the tables and do individual bootstrap columns?

Attached is an example of a table row.[image]

Comment: It will be great if you will add any demo/jsfiddle with code you have tried.

Comment: See this URL: http://output.jsbin.com/uBeQERiJ/1

Comment: Thanks @JagdishParmar is that possible in tabular data? I know it can be done in standard columns/rows.

Comment: @Leothelion great suggestion here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/a6691013/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6691013/3/). I'm assuming that you have alerts throughout each of your rows, therefore we're iterating through each `<tr>` and finding the `.alert` divs, then determining which alert has the most "height". Then we add this `height` CSS to every `.alert` in the row.

**The HTML structure has changed, I've added `<thead>` and `<tbody>`**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Super Permits</th>
        <th>Active?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ....
        ....

$('.table').find('tbody tr').each(function (e) {
  var heights = $(".alert").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).outerHeight();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

  $(this).find('.alert').css('height', maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly but did have the action of making the all the rows the same height. It won't be an issue with my project but worth mentioning for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add custom css for the "alert" class, and it will apply to all alert types, like:

```
.alert {
   height: 90px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/W3AVE/4j72mfeo/

Comment: Incredibly simple and effective. This wasn't as robust of a solution as others but could work very good for something like a max 2 lines or something.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class='same-height'>
    <td><div><span>text</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>some long text here</span></div></td>
    <td><div><span>text medium</span></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
```

JS

```
(function($){

  var $el   = $(".same-height"),
      h     = $el.height();

  $el.find("div").each(function()
  {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.css({"height": h});
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: thanks for submitting, this is pretty similar to what someone else suggested. I gave them the answer point just because they clarified a bit more and made a JSfiddle with it.