# How to set all Bootstrap 3 cells in a row to the same height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid of flippable cards with variable content and try to set the `height` of cards with less content to the same value as the card with the maximum content. But no matter to which box/cell I apply `height:100%`, the smaller cells stay just as large as they need to. I can see that the row itself naturally has the maximum *height*, but why can't all child cells inherit that *height*?

Here is the example: http://www.bootply.com/NnHFEKwrwu

Comment: Make it a table cell: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height CSS only solution. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To understand `height`, this will only take up the specified `height` that is applied, meaning that if your container element has a height of *300px*, and that child element therefore has the CSS `height:100%`, THEN that child element will take on that height.

In your case, you really haven't specified a `height` on any of the elements, only `height:100%` and `min-height:100%`. More than likely, your `min-height` will always be a set number, meaning `px, em`, etc.

What I'm *assuming* you want is to have ALL the boxes the same height. If this is the case, then you can see a previous answer that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044473/bootstrap-same-height-on-table-alert-divs/34045229#34045229). The objective is to get all XX elements (that you want to group), and determine the `max-height` of the group. We then apply this `height` to all the elements in the group.

This happens a lot when you want carousels, modals, tooltips, or in your case, columns, to be the same height throughout, and therefore making your layout look a lot nicer.

In your case, you'd want to iterate through all the `.card` elements and get the max-height of those, then apply it to the group. I like to use `outerHeight()` b/c this will get the `border, padding, and margin` as well.

```
var maxHeightOfCards = $('.card').map(function() {
    return $(this).outerHeight();
  }).get();

// or use $('.card').css('height', Math.max.apply(null, maxHeightOfCards))
$('.card').height(Math.max.apply(null, maxHeightOfCards));
```

Answer (score 0):

...although there are many things wrong in your code, the solution you are looking for is easier than you think:

```
.row {
  display:tab
}
.row > div {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
  height:100%;
}
```

It's as simple as it gets. Then you can use `height:100%` to the children elements.